# Why I am getting this specific error when entering the formula in the cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to apply this formula in cell D14 of sheet Lease

```
=LET(
     _date, C14#,
     _nlb, Input!B23,
     _clb, Input!B17,
     _rentd, 'RBump'!D6:O6,
     _rentbr, 'RBump'!D7:O7,
     _rentdd, 'RBump'!D10:K10,
     _rentddbr, 'RBump'!D11:K11,
     BYROW(_date, LAMBDA(ddd,IFS(
     ddd>=_nlb, LOOKUP(ddd, _rentd, _rentbr),
     ddd<_clb, LOOKUP(ddd, _rentdd, _rentddbr)))))
```

When I press enter it gives me error as

```
You can't include a parameter to a LET function after defining its calculation.
```

What should I do, to make the formula work, it is not even letting to enter and gives the error message.

The ranges _rentd, _rentbr, _rentdd & _rentddbr are all formula calculated cells.

Comment: Does your version of Excel allow BYROW/LAMBDA?

Comment: But if you type `=BYR` does it show `BYROW` as an option? There's an older version which does not support LAMBDA and some other new functions, like WRAPROWS, TOROW, etc.

Comment: Works for me after cleaning up the sheet names (produces a series of #N/As as data is not found). Maybe it is indeed a question of your version.